# Setting ControlID to be used for AutoIT

Tags: autoit, windows, windows-controls

I am trying to do some automated functional testing for a windows app and I just got my hands on AutoIT. Looks like most (if not all) standard windows applications have a Control ID set. Unfortunately, the Control ID field is blank when i mouse hover using the Finder tool. So looks like the application (written in C) hasnt set a ID to each element?

I've used XCode's UI Automation for iPad apps and we use "setAccessibilityIdenitifier" to uniquely identify each field. I am trying to find out the equivalent for a Windows application.

That begs the question, is AutoIT even the correct tool? All my testing is calculation based. So you can assume 2 input fields and one output. So if the user enters 5, and 2 and hits "Add", I need to check if the output is 7. So i need to uniquely identify each element.

I also noticed when there is a group of elements, when i hover my mouse over the group, i get "Static" as the classname and only the coordinates change when i try to access each element, and every other control like Instance, ClassNameNN all remain the same. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to the AutoIT forum guys, the group issue is fixed - http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/151055-autoit-basics/

I still need to know how to set Control IDs from the application side C code

Comment: "written in C" is not verbose enough. What framework do you use for GUI?

Comment: By the way, you do not need ControlIDs to read or write data to controls. It can be an optional parameter. Try it with "".

Comment: @Xeno: Yeah, it is an optional parameter. But i require a hook to pull out specific information - Looks like i cant use Control ID or ClassNN right now. Perhaps, after using Windows Forms, I will be able to use the "Name" field.